# Compare Tuples in Rust

Tags: rust, tuples

I'm writing a test case for a function which returns a tuple including an enum. I want to verify that the returned tuple matches what I am expecting.

How I do compare tuples composed of enums in Rust? The following fails to compile:

```rust
enum Test {
  Foo,
  Bar
}
assert_eq!((1, Test::Foo), (1, Test::Foo));
```

(Of course, one of those tuples is generated at runtime by a method.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tuples already implement `PartialEq` and `Debug` if all their elements do, but you're missing both a `Debug` and `PartialEq` implementation for your custom enum:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
enum Test {
  Foo,
  Bar
}
```

With that your expected `assert_eq!((1, Test::Foo), (1, Test::Foo));` works.

If you can't implement either trait you can use [`matches!(<value>, <pattern>)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/macro.matches.html):

```rust
let got = (1, Test::Foo); // calculate your result
assert!(matches!(got, (1, Test::Foo)))
```

Note that the second parameter, `<pattern>`, has to be a [pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html) and thus must be known at compile time (your call to a function will need to be passed as the first parameter).